# Neural network inference with one image: Why is GPU utilization not 100%?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gpu, inference

First of all: this question is connected to neural network inference and not training.

I have discovered, that when doing inference of a trained neural network with only one image over and over on a GPU (e.g. P100) the utilization of the computing power with Tensorflow is not reaching 100%, but instead around 70%. This is also the case if the image does not have to be transferred to the GPU. Therefore, the issue has to be connected to constraints in the parallelization of the calculations. My best guesses for the reasons are:

- *Tensorflow* can only *utilize* the parallelization capabilities of a GPU up to a certain level. (Also the higher utilization of the same model as a TensorRT models suggest that). In this case, the question is: What is the reason for that?
- The inherent *neural network structure* with several subsequent layers avoids that a higher usage is possible. Therefore the problem is not overhead of a framework but lies in the general design of neural networks. In this case, the question is: What are the restrictions to that?
- Both of the above combined.

Thanks for your ideas on the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect the GPU utilization to go to 100% when you run the neuronal network prediction for one image?

The GPU utilization is per time unit (e.g. 1 second). This means, when the neuronal network algorithm finished before this time unit elapsed (e.g within 0.5s) Then the rest of the time the GPU may get used by other programs or not get used at all. If the GPU is not used by any other programs neither then well you will not reach 100%.

Comment: and who tells you that the gpu code is not taking less then 1ms? Actually given you have 1GHz one milliseconds is quite long (1GHz equals to 1.0E-6 milliseconds)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nevertheless, I see two points why this is not answering the question: First, the evaluation of the neural network on the single image is repeated infinitely. Second, you can track with nvidia-smi up to 1 ms. Still the effect persists.

Comment: How do you make the operation repeat infinitely? By CPU or by GPU code? If it is by CPU code then it may be that the CPU is not creating the CPU load fasten enough in order to reach 100% GPU load.

Comment: Additionally, I can easily track that the execution of the network is not faster than 1 ms.

Comment: How can you track that the execution of the network is slower than 1ms?

Comment: E.g. run it once and track nvidia-smi -lms 1 which is higher than 0% for bigger 1 ms.

Comment: If you run nvidia-smi -lms 1 without the neuronal network code running ... Isn't the output also > 0% since the operation system, a webbrowser, further programs use the GPU too? How can you then conclude that it is the neuronal network alone that creates something bigger then 0%? You need to take into account the sampling theorem, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem